# An Updated Salesforce's Picklist does'nt render a new value just added

Tags: salesforce, picklist

I am new in Salesforce and I need to add a new value in a picklist. Once added, I save, but when a I need to create a new record of the object within which there is the picklist, the new value is not rendered. Someone can explain me why?? Thanks

I tried by adding the new value by editing the picklist.

Answer (score 0):

Does your object have "record types"? Like "ok, all accounts go to 1 database table but hospitals/factories/marketing agencies need different fields visible, different rules around what is required and even if they use same picklists - values on the picklists may differ". When you were adding that new picklist value it probably asked you to which (if any) record types you want it added...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should make sure the picklist value is active. Then make sure that the user profile viewing the page has visibility to that record type. this can be checked under Profile > Object settings > Work Order (or object that applies). After checking make sure that picklist field value was added to the appropriate record type.Please give feedback if u managed to get this done.